# SNS Apple platform delivery failure logs are missing

Tags: ios, amazon-sns

We are using Amazon SNS as a solution to deliver notifications to 4 of our mobile app's - for each app we have both a GCM as APNS app created in SNS. We've enabled the delivery status loggin for each app both on GCM as APNS (100%). And for all these app's we have received successfull and failure requests in cloudwatch, on top of this we've created a monitoring solution that is querying on the correlated cloudwatch logs.

A few weeks back we noticed that we where missing the delivery logging for all Apple applications - from a certain date no logs where received. We've enabled it again, received logs and now a few weeks later it's disabled again.

Initially we thought the "Apple" applications lost their Delivery Tracking options with renewing the yearly certificate. But we did a test (re-upload the cert) and that did not adapt the delivery failure tracking.

We did a query on CloudTrail on the event "SetPlatformApplicationAttributes" but no events popped up - besides our tests.

At this point in time we have no clue why it keeps getting disabled.

Are we missing some critical info? Is it normal that for Apple apps the delivery tracking is disabled after x-amount of time? What are best-practices for setting this up?

Comment: Currently we have a timer based function that will check the delivery log configuration, if it's disabled we enable it again.